# Chrome developer breaks on refresh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I tested this on multiple sites and I have the same problem everywhere. When I refresh the site in Chrome with developer tools open, the site stops and its stuck on loading. In developer tools opens the tab Sources with bundle.js file code and I get and error in console:

*Cannot read property 'dataset' of null*

Why is this error occurring and how can I resolve this? I tried to restart my computer but its not working. Disabling JavaScript in Chrome is not an option. I have Chrome Version 52.0.2743.116.

Comment: I'm not having this issue. Could you provide an example website where this happens and the exact steps you take to reproduce? It could well be a Chrome Extension that is causing the problem.

Comment: Hello, this happens on every site. If I go to orf.at and the open Developer extension i click refresh site and it starts loading and as i wrote before i get some error from bundle.js

Comment: Go to chrome://extensions/ and un-check the enabled extensions (other than the standard Google ones). Re-load Chrome and try again. See if that makes a difference.

Comment: I disabled all the extension and its still not working...

Comment: How about creating a new Chrome profile. Click on your name in the top right corner, click 'Switch person' and then click 'Add person'. This will run Chrome in a clean environment without caches, plugins etc. I suspect that will do it.